# How to return several columns for subquery added to select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
select 
   e.field1,
   e.field2,
   (select count(field3) from tbl1 where someField = e.field1 group By someType ) as count_1,
   (select count(field4) from tbl1 where someField = e.field1 group By someType ) as count_2,
from
...
```

I don't like code duplication for counts but if I do smth like

```
select count(field3), count(field3) ....
```

in subquery postgres complains that subquery must return single column.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select e.field1,  e.field2, t1.*
from e left join lateral
     (seclect count(tbl1.field3) as count_1, count(tbl1.field4) as count_4
      from tbl1
      where tbl1.someField = e.field1
     ) t1
     on true;
```

You can also do this with aggregation:

```
select e.field1,  e.field2, t1.count_1, t1.count_2
from e left join
     (select tbl1.someField, count(tbl1.field3) as count_1, count(tbl1.field4) as count_2
      from tbl1
      group by tbl1.someField 
     ) t1
     on tbl1.someField = e.field1;
```

This could return `NULL` values, which you can convert to `0` if desired using `coalesce()`.

Comment: I need an universal query which will have the same syntax for postgres and oracle

Comment: oracle version 11

Comment: @gstackoverflow . . . The first solution works in Oracle 12C+ and Postgres, which seems reasonable given the tags on your questions.  I added an alternative solution that should work anywhere.

Comment: I originally used this approach but performance was awful